# Does overriding Angular Material Global style classes within a client component change the style globally?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

If we override one of the Angular Material styles for a component within another component, does the override get scoped to the new component only?

For example suppose we change the expansion panel CSS like this within `app.component.css`:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-spacing {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Will this rule apply to the `app.component.html` template only (Assuming view encapsulation is turned on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Set encapsolation to none you overwrite the styles global

Look at [angular docu](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)